# What is the difference between scipy.optimize import linprog package versus ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp package?

Tags: scipy, linear-programming, or-tools, scipy-optimize

What is the difference between scipy.optimize import linprog package versus ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp package, I would like to develope an optimize function to in my project where I need to build an optimize function. Can anyone please help me to understand the difference between this t

Comment: Might be better to post it here: https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The APIs are very different. I would suggest to implement a sample problem with both. That will give you a good understanding before making a decision.

Comment: Besides different APIs, ortools supports multiple solvers (when install was customized) and it's default-solver (always available; simplex-based) is much more advanced than both of scipy's (especially the simplex one). Furthermore, at least with customized installs, mixed-integer programming is supported.